# Java Logic error on run of loop: If/else counter incorrectly counting

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, logic, accumulator

Please let me know if this one is too vague:

I have a loop that compiles and runs but it doesn't perform as I would like.
I'm trying to count the times an if/else choice is made so long as the loop runs then display the number of times that choice has been made.

The choices work, The loop works, but if I code the choice not picked to be counted as 0, then if the other choice was picked the next time around the accumulated count of the first choice is returned to 0.  Or both choices are accumulated.

I have 4 if/else questions but they are similarly coded to act the same way.  If I can just fix one, I can fix the rest.

Here is the relevant parts of the code.  (I have been asked in the past to not put so much code if only part is acting up.)

```
int choiceCount;
int choiceCount2;

       while(quitYn == 1)
  {

     System.out.println("I am ready for the next participant.");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("What would you rather have?");
     System.out.println("Enter 1 for Love or 2 for Money.");
     surveyChoice = input.nextInt();

     if(surveyChoice == 1)
     {
        choice = FIRST_PICK;
        message = "Love";
        choiceCount = ++ FIRST_CHOICE - 1;
        choiceCount2 = ++ SECOND_CHOICE - 3;
     }
     else if(surveyChoice == 2)
     {
        choice = SECOND_PICK;   
        message = "Money"; 
        choiceCount = ++ FIRST_CHOICE - 1;
        choiceCount2 = ++ SECOND_CHOICE - 2;
     }
     else 
     {
        choice = "Broken dreams";
        message = "Broken dreams";
        choiceCount = ++ FIRST_CHOICE - 2;
        choiceCount2 = ++ SECOND_CHOICE - 3;
     }
System.out.println(choiceCount + "Participants chose" + FIRST_PICK);
     System.out.println(choiceCount2 + "Participants chose" + SECOND_PICK);
```

Comment: Please explain this code: `choiceCount = ++ FIRST_CHOICE - 1;` Seems like you just want `choiceCount++;` but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Looks like java, please add java tag.

Comment: If I put choice count in every part, then I get a count even for choices that were not picked.  I'm trying to get it to know when not to count and when to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your questions understanding, you need something like this

```
int choiceCount = 0;
int choiceCount2 = 0;

while(quitYn == 1)
{

 System.out.println("I am ready for the next participant.");
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println("What would you rather have?");
 System.out.println("Enter 1 for Love or 2 for Money.");
 surveyChoice = input.nextInt();

 if(surveyChoice == 1)
 {
    choice = FIRST_PICK;
    message = "Love";
    choiceCount++;
 }
 else if(surveyChoice == 2)
 {
    choice = SECOND_PICK;   
    message = "Money";
    choiceCount2++;
 }
 else 
 {
    choice = "Broken dreams";
    message = "Broken dreams";

 }
 }
 System.out.println(choiceCount + "Participants chose" + FIRST_PICK);
 System.out.println(choiceCount2 + "Participants chose" + SECOND_PICK);
```

Comment: That might work only then I get the error that the variable choiceCount might not be initialized because there is no mention of it in the else if and the else options.

Comment: You won't get an error about uninitialized variable `choiceCount` or `choiceCount2` with the code from the answer.  It differs from the code in your question in that where the variables are declared they are initialized to have the value 0.  The first line of the code in the answer reads `int choiceCount = 0;` which initializes `choiceCount` to have the value `0`.

Comment: I didn't change my choiceCout to 0

Comment: I missed that.  I trimmed the fat and got rid of extra code and simplified it.  I was over thinking it.

Comment: Thanks to Sandesh and Evan